# On Ubuntu 18.04, I cannot change the owner of folders that are in my shared VirtualBox folder; how can I make myself, not root, owner?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, permissions

I am using a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, and I am working on a Wordpress project with Nginx. I installed VBox guest additions, but I cannot change the owner of the shared folder, which I have set to auto mount in the /opt folder; the path to the shared folder is /opt/myfolder/THISFOLDER. I want to edit contents (files) inside THISFOLDER. I have tried the command `sudo chmod -aG vboxsf myusername` and rebooted to no avail. When I do `sudo chown -R myusername /opt/myfolder`, it also doesn't do anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`cd /opt/myfolder ; pwd` - verify that pwd prints `/opt/myfolder` and nothing else, then `sudo chown -R myusername:mygroup *`

1. to run sudo in "local" folder is a bit safer w.r.t. errors.
   (hint: try `echo *` and press enter)
2. Also set group, this might be your actual problem - i.e. keeping the current group attempting to set yourself as the owner. If you're not member of that group it will likely fail *(not verified)*.

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: Have a look at what numbers you have in `cat /etc/group` (groups) and `cat /etc/passwd` (user IDs) - then compare to what you see with `ls -ln` in the folder and possibly in some subfolders. Also check inside the virtual machine in the same way... a virtualbox/vmware document check might reveal something.